# Hide thead but keep its cells width in tbody

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I always use Bootstrap grid classes in `thead th` tags so I'll no longer need repeating classes on `tbody` cells. for example:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-2">#</th>
            <th class="col-xs-10">Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>150</td><td>Long text in here</td></tr>
        <tr><td>150</td><td>Long text in here</td></tr>
        <tr><td>150</td><td>Long text in here</td></tr>
        <tr><td>150</td><td>Long text in here</td></tr>
        <tr><td>150</td><td>Long text in here</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I'm implementing a scenario that I should not use table headers. I tried `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` on thead but none of them works.

I guess I have following solutions (which are all bad INMHO!):

- Add grid classes to each `tbody` cell (which in my large dynamic table is a bad thing)
- Use css to target cells by the index eg: `nth-child()` which is also bad, because of duplicated CSS rules, and will be a pain in the ass becase table may dynamically change and I'll always need a SCSS compile!
- Give `thead` a `1px` height, with no inner text or anything.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: you don't want the table headers to display? then why not try removing from your code?.

Comment: Add the sizes to your first cells in the tbody

Comment: Works why shouldn't it? https://jsfiddle.net/8brbuy6v

Comment: @ooo-Ghost-ooo I need the sizes, I think I described the situation in my question

Comment: @JohannKratzik Are you sure grids are working on tbody cells?

Comment: @Daniel How? CSS or html classes?

Comment: th is similar to a td, just styled diferent. If those classes work on th, hey will work on td.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [@Johann Kratzik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7226072/johann-kratzik) suggestion, I managed to solve my own problem by hiding `thead` contents and using `height: 0` on `thead` itself.

```
thead { opacity: 0; border: 0 none; height: 0; }
thead * { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0 none; height: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
thead p {
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Of course the p is just an example, you can do this with any other tag.

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8brbuy6v/1